# ios 8 + xcode 6.01 + presentnavigationController + Screen does not rotate

Tags: xcode, ios8, landscape, autorotate

Am presenting
 [window addSubview:navigationController.view];

```
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

LicenceAgreementViewController *licenceAgreementViewController = [[LicenceAgreementViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LicenceAgreementViewController" bundle:nil];


[self.navigationController presentViewController :licenceAgreementViewController animated:YES completion:nil];


[licenceAgreementViewController release];
```

And also did some changes in .plist itself 
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{

```
NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

if(self.window.rootViewController){

    UIViewController *presentedViewController = [[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] lastObject];

    orientations = [presentedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];

   // orientations = [presentedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];

}
```